# Automate login to website useing VBA - Get "automation Error" "Unspecified error" 2147467259 (80004005)

Tags: vba

I have had success using website logins in the past, but for some reason the last two websites I tried to automate have not worked at all.  Perhaps it is because they are jhtml and aspx sites, I do not know.  Below is the aspx example.  Hopefully what works with this will work with the other.

```
Sub ws8c()

Dim appIEc As SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium ' InternetExplorer
Set appIEc = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
appIEc.navigate "http://www.bentekenergy.com/Login.aspx"

While appIEc.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

' I get the error here! if I comment this out I get the error here too
appIEc.document.getElementById("ctl00_MasterMainContent_LoginCtrl_Username").Value = "MyUserName"

'if I comment the above line out I get the error here too
appIEc.document.getElementById("ctl00_MasterMainContent_LoginCtrl_Password").Value = "MyPW"

' This part doesn't work either... 
Set ElementCol = appIEc.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each btna In ElementCol
If btna.ID = "ctl00_MasterMainContent_LoginCtrl_btnSignIn" Then
btna.Click
Exit For
End If
Next btna

While appIEc.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

appIEc.navigate "http://www.bentekenergy.com/Benport/HubFlowMaps.aspx?sg=6", CLng(2048)

Set appIEc = Nothing

End Sub
```

I tried using other techniques like getelementsbytagname("input") and then looping through and looking for the ID is have shown above.  I have to admit I am kind of pulling together snips from other peoples posts so I might be missing something major.  Whats crazy is I have very similar code working elsewhere....

Answer (score 0):

You should decide what the Security Settings (Integrity Level) you need for your application.

From my understanding Internet Explorer by default uses Low Integrity application settings.

The Integrity Settings are defined in the User Access Controls (UAC) for Windows 7 and the UAC defines which programs are trusted by the system to make certain changes.

When you initially declared the variable appIEC, you declared it as shDocView.InternetExplorerMedium,  which indicates that you want to use the object (Internet Explorer) with Medium Integrity settings.

Yet, when you created the object in the set statement you created it using the default Low Integrity settings.

From my experience, websites set as Trusted Sites run under Medium Integrity, but won't run under Low Integrity.  Similarly, website that are trusted must run under Medium/High Integrity, otherwise automation error occurs.

Hope this helps!!